# Start Vault Server in Dev mode using vault.service file

Tags: vault

I have tried to give a custom config file to start the vault server, in the vault.service file and is working as expected.
But if i try to start the vault server in dev mode changing
`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vault/vault server -dev`, in this case service exits.

On the other hand if I manually run `/usr/local/bin/vault/vault server -dev`, vault server is getting started in dev mode.

Is it possible to run vault server in dev mode using vault as a service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research I have come to an understanding  that, Yes we can run dev mode as a service.
Dev mode creates a token in /home/user_mentioned and home for that user should also be created. Or we need to set the home path for that particular user.